# SQL to display entire rows of data that contain duplicate values within ONE column

Tags: mysql, sql

I've searched for the solution to this problem, but none of the solutions are getting me quite what I need.

I have three columns: inputDate, orderID, employeeID.

I want to find out if orderID is repeated, and I want to find out which 2 (or more) employee IDs both input that order, and when.

Example data:

```
inputDate            orderID    employeeID
2018-10-30 10:24:56  234264     45
2018-10-30 10:26:12  473897     45
2018-10-30 10:29:59  879546     1
2018-10-30 11:01:04  987654     1
2018-10-30 11:01:04  165498     1
2018-10-30 16:12:59  654321     5
2018-10-30 16:26:25  654321     1
2018-10-30 16:42:02  879546     17
```

OrderID 654321 is in there twice, and so is 879546. I need the output to be something along the lines of:

```
inputDate            OrderID    employeeID
2018-10-30 16:12:59  654321     5
2018-10-30 16:26:25  654321     1
2018-10-30 10:29:59  879546     1
2018-10-30 16:42:02  879546     17
```

OR (better):

```
orderID employeeID1 inputDate1          employeeID2 inputDate2
654321  1           2018-10-30 16:12:59 5           2018-10-30 16:26:25
879546  1           2018-10-30 10:29:59 17          2018-10-30 16:42:02
```

And I need it to come to that output based on the fact that '654321' and '879546' are duplicate values.

---

I was able to find a dumb solution by doing:

```
SELECT orderID,MIN(employeeID),MIN(inputDate),MAX(employeeID),MAX(inputDate)
FROM `ordersPacked`
GROUP BY orderID
HAVING count(orderID)>1
```

Which gave me:

```
orderID   MIN(employeeID)   MIN(inputDate)        MAX(employeeID)   MAX(inputDate)  
654321    1                 2018-10-30 16:12:59   5                 2018-10-30 16:26:25
879546    1                 2018-10-30 10:29:59   17                2018-10-30 16:42:02
```

I mean, yeah, that's technically what I'm looking for, but it's not a legitimate solution. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can aggregate the data and concatenate the columns together:

```
SELECT orderID,
       GROUP_CONCAT(employeeID, '-', inputDate)
FROM ordersPacked op
GROUP BY orderID
HAVING count(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a filter on IDORDER

```
SELECT * FROM `ordersPacked` WHERE OrderID IN (SELECT OrderID FROM `ordersPacked` GROUP BY OrderID HAVING count(orderID)>1) ORDER BY OrderID, inputDate
```